# Code first migrations não funciona

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

Fiz numa camada separada chamada ´Data´

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context() : base("EscolaContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Escola> Escolas { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Turma> Turmas { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Aluno> Alunos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Escola>().HasKey(c => c.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Escola>().Property(c => c.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Escola>().Property(c => c.Nome).HasMaxLength(100);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Escola>().Property(c => c.Cnpj).HasMaxLength(14);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Turma>().HasKey(c => c.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Turma>().Property(c => c.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Turma>().Property(c => c.Nome).HasMaxLength(100);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Aluno>().HasKey(c => c.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Aluno>().Property(c => c.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Aluno>().Property(c => c.Nome).HasMaxLength(100);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Aluno>().Property(c => c.Matricula).HasMaxLength(20);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>().HasKey(c => c.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>().Property(c => c.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>().Property(c => c.Login).HasMaxLength(20);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>().Property(c => c.Senha).HasMaxLength(8);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Turma>().HasRequired(c => c.Escola).WithMany(p => p.Turmas).HasForeignKey(p => p.IdEscola);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Aluno>().HasRequired(c => c.Turma).WithMany(p => p.Alunos).HasForeignKey(p => p.IdTurma);
    }
```

Ao executar o comando `Enable-Migrations` não deu nenhum erro. Mas o banco e as tabelas não foram criadas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O comando **`Enable-Migrations`** apenas ativa o recurso de migrações.

Para atualizar o banco de dados é preciso criar uma *migration* e atualizar a base, rodando os seguintes comandos no *Package Manager Console*.

Criar a migration

> Add-Migration NomeDaMigration

Atualizar a base

> Update-Database

---

Também é possível atualizar o banco sem precisar criar *migrations*, isso é útil em tempo de desenvolvimento, quando o banco muda muito rápido e com muita frequência.

Ao rodar o comando `Enable-Migrations` vai ser criada uma pasta **Migrations** e dentro dela uma classe `Configuration`, dentro dessa classe é possível mudar esta configuração.

```
// Construtor da classe Configuration
public Configuration()
{
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
}
```

Com isso, a partir de então só é preciso rodar o comando `Update-Database` pra atualizar a base.